# How to handle state in Material UI Data Grid's components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to add search functionality to a data grid component. In order to achieve this, I'm adding an input element to the table using the `components.header` prop as follows (I've omitted irrelevant code):

```
const Table = () => {
  const filterRows = (rows) => {
    return rows;
  };
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const Header = () => (
    <input
      value={searchTerm}
      onChange={(event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500 }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={searchTerm ? filterRows(orders) : orders}
        columns={orderColumns}
        components={{
          header: () => <Header />
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The issue I'm having is that the input element loses focus each time a character is entered into the input in the header. Presumably, this is because it updates state, which triggers a re-render. This makes it impossible to share and access state of anything contained inside the Data Grid's components **because it requires a `React.FC` argument and won't accept a `ReactElement`** so the input is always re-rendered.

Am I missing something or is this actually not possible with Material UI's Data Grid? It seems like a pretty expected use-case to have something stateful in the header that we'd want to access like a controlled input component in order to use it as a kind of "Tool bar" as mentioned in the Material UI docs.

I've created a code sandbox to replicate the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keldysh-z995k?file=/src/App.js:246-726.

Cheers.